# How to use deleteview for particular user and particular item in Django?

Tags: python, django, view

I have these models. Each reply can have none, one or more post. Post is user specific. How to make delete view so that user can only delete his post and not of posts by other on a reply. 
I tried this many time but my view is deleting post of some other user as well. Means any user can delete post of any other user. 
I want to make a button next to each post to delete, but button should be seen only to those who have written the post.

```
class Reply(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Question = models.ForeignKey(Doubt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply = models.TextField(max_length=40000)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_image_path, null = True, blank = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def Post(self):
        return reverse("community:post", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})



class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    reply = models.ForeignKey(Reply, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: Can you show the view that you've tried to use to handle the delete?

Answer (score 5):

If you have the `AuthenticationMiddleware` enabled in `settings.py`, the request object in a view function will include a user model. Your view will then look something like this:

```
from django import http

def get_post_from_request(request):
    ... something to pull up the post object from the request ...
    return the_post

def delete_post(request):
    the_post = get_post_from_request(request)
    if request.user == the_post.User:
        the_post.delete()
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect("/your/success/url/")
    else:
        return http.HttpResponseForbidden("Cannot delete other's posts")
```

If you're using generic class based views, your view might look more like this:

```
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
from django import http

class PostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/your/success/url/'

    # override the delete function to check for a user match
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # the Post object
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.User == request.user:
            success_url = self.get_success_url()
            self.object.delete()
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
        else:
            return http.HttpResponseForbidden("Cannot delete other's posts")
```

If you'd like help navigating class based views (they have a dense inheritance hierarchy) I can recommend http://ccbv.co.uk - their breakdown on the Delete view is [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/)

Answer (score 1):

For class based views the logic should be in form_valid() for it to work, not delete(). If the logic is put in delete() the terminal will throw a warning:

```
 DeleteView uses FormMixin to handle POST requests. As a consequence, any custom deletion logic in MonitorDeleteView.delete() handler should be moved to form_valid().
```

Simply putting it in form_valid() fixes the warning and makes the code work:

```py
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
from django import http

class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/your/success/url/'

    # override the form_valid function to check for a user match
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.User == request.user:
            success_url = self.get_success_url()
            self.object.delete()
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
        else:
            return http.HttpResponseForbidden("Cannot delete other's posts")
```